# Did anyone give these smart pointers (auto_any, scoped_any, shared_any) a test drive?

Tags: c++, memory, smart-pointers

I'm investigating smart pointers with "shared" functionality for Windows CE and Mobile, where the VS 2008 tr1 `std::shared_ptr` cannot be used (due to linkage to a v.9 dll not present on CE, obviously, if I understand it correctly).

There's a semi-old MSDN Magazine article with sources from a Microsoftie (Eric Niebler): [Achieve More Reliable Resource Management with Our Custom C++ Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164130.aspx).

The reasoning, design and implementation of his `shared_any` looks solid, but I'm wondering if anyone ever actually tested the lot on any platform (not necessarily WinCe/WM)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to use [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm). As I understand it, the Boost.SmartPointer library is a header-only library, and so you can just copy over the headers you need from Boost to get everything working.

Comment: Be sure not to use boost::shared_ptr with an array unless you specify a destructing function in the shared_ptr constructor. This is unwieldy without lambda syntax, so you may want to also use boost::shared_array

Comment: @Steve: There's no problem using boost::shared_ptr elements in a std::vector, right?

Comment: @Johann, that should be fine, the vector will call the object's destrutor when it goes out of scope